# Java applet not loading with Java Plugin 1.6

Tags: java, applet

I created an applet and added it to my JSP page. It was working fine in IE, Chrome when Java Plugin version was 1.5. Recently, I updated Java plugin to 1.6 and now the applet is not loading. The following error is displayed on the console.

```
load: class GraphApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GraphApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://cwrug26999:8080/fluids/pages/GraphApplet/class.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GraphApplet.class
```

The GraphApplet.class is located in the same location where JSP page is located.

**I used IE with Java 1.5 plugin and the applet is loading fine.**

Can anyone point out what I am missing here.

The source code that I am using in the JSP file is below:

```
<br><center><applet code="GraphApplet.class" codebase="pages/" width="450" height="450">
</applet></center>
```

Sorry, the applet can not be accessed publicly.

I am using Tomcat5 as the web server and under webapps I have my project folder "fluids" and under this folder I have "pages" folder which contains the JSP files and the applet .class files.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code you wrote for deploying applet? Also make sure that files are there at the server. Try cleaning/republishing the server again.

Comment: Is the applet publicly accessible?  What URL can we visit it at?

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://cwrug26999:8080/fluids/pages/GraphApplet/class.class` looks as if the plugin interpreted the `code` attribute as a class name, not a file name. Try using `code=GraphApplet` instead.

You could also try using the [`<embed>` tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#embed) which isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, after lots of trial and errors it was related to Java Cache. I deleted the Java Cache by going to Control Panel->Java->Temporary Internet Folder->Delete Files...

I also changed the location where the cache files were stored and apparently, the default location was write-protected.

Phew...

Anyway, thanks for the replies